# AWS Cognito with the serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to implement Cognito into my nodejs app for user management using the serverless framework.
I'm stuck at configuring the IdentityPoolRoleAttachment. I have a role for cognito/fb/google provided identities and this is what I have come up with:

```
CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
  DependsOn: UserPoolAuthenticatedRole
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
    RoleMappings:
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - UserPoolAuthenticatedRole
            - UserPoolUnauthenticatedRole
      "graph.facebook.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - FacecookAuthenticatedRole
            - FacecookUnauthenticatedRole
      "accounts.google.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - GoogleAuthenticatedRole
            - GoogleUnauthenticatedRole
```

Googling around and searching the docs only show how to configure the attachment with just a Cognito User Pool, how can I add in the roles for FB/Google? If i try to deploy this it fails with:

```
ServerlessError: An error occurred: CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment - Internal Failure.
```

Which isn't much help. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full config just in case:

```
CognitoUserPoolStandardUserPool:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  Properties:
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireLowercase: true
        RequireNumbers: true
        RequireSymbols: false
        RequireUppercase: true
    Schema:
      #- Name: name
      #  AttributeDataType: String
      #  Mutable: true
      #  Required: true
      - Name: email
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: false
        Required: true
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
      - email

CognitoUserPoolClientStandardUserPoolClient:
  DependsOn: CognitoUserPoolStandardUserPool
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
  Properties:
    ClientName: Standard_Users
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoUserPoolStandardUserPool
    RefreshTokenValidity: 1
    GenerateSecret: false

CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool:
  DependsOn: CognitoUserPoolClientStandardUserPoolClient
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
  Properties:
    AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
    SupportedLoginProviders:
      "graph.facebook.com": ${self:provider.config.FB_APP_ID}
      "accounts.google.com": ${self:provider.config.GOOGL_WEB_ID}
    CognitoIdentityProviders:
      - ClientId: 
          Ref: CognitoUserPoolClientStandardUserPoolClient
        ProviderName:
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - CognitoUserPoolStandardUserPool
            - ProviderName
        ServerSideTokenCheck: true

# Authentiacted users can call API Gateway
UserPoolAuthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: UserPoolAuthRole
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: UserPoolAuthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "execute-api:Invoke"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

FacebookAuthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: FacebookAuthRole
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "graph.facebook.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "graph.facebook.com:app_id": ${self:provider.config.FB_APP_ID}
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: FacebookAuthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "execute-api:Invoke"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

GoogleAuthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: GoogleAuthRole
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "accounts.google.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "accounts.google.com:aud": ${self:provider.config.GOOGL_WEB_ID}
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: GoogleAuthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "execute-api:Invoke"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

# Unauthenticated users can only authenticate
UserPoolUnauthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": unauthenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: UserPoolUnauthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "cognito-identity:*"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

FacecookUnauthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "graph.facebook.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": ${self:provider.config.FB_APP_ID}
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: FacebookUnauthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "cognito-identity:*"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

GoogleUnauthenticatedRole:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated:
              - "accounts.google.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": ${self:provider.config.GOOGL_WEB_ID}
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: GoogleUnauthenticatedPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "cognito-identity:*"
              Resource: "*"
    MaxSessionDuration: 3600

CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
  DependsOn: UserPoolAuthenticatedRole
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
    RoleMappings:
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - UserPoolAuthenticatedRole
            - UserPoolUnauthenticatedRole
      "graph.facebook.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - FacecookAuthenticatedRole
            - FacecookUnauthenticatedRole
      "accounts.google.com":
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
        RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - GoogleAuthenticatedRole
            - GoogleUnauthenticatedRole
```